# Is potential energy a real form of energy?

Tags: energy, potential-energy

Is potential energy a tangible form of energy that an object possesses due to its position or configuration, or is it simply a concept used to estimate how much energy an object will have in the future when specific conditions, like motion or release, occur?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I owe you one hundred dollars. Is this debt a tangible asset that you own now, or is it a measure of how much extra money you will have if and when I repay the debt ? It is both at the same time.

Comment: So, is potential energy essentially the energy required to position an object against a force, and is this energy retained within the object?

Comment: @IbrahimKhalil, This question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672596/what-does-potential-energy-really-mean, and the accepted answer and its comments might help

Comment: @IbrahimKhalil You should think of potential energy as being a property of the configuration of a system, rather than of an individual object. For example, the potential energy that is created when a weight is lifted is a property of the weight, the Earth, and the gravitational field between them. Trying to locate potential energy at one specific place almost always leads to confusion.